# MongoDB Search for documents by passing parameters of an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

```
Matches.find({
  user_one: [
    {
      user: userId,
      punctuation: { $gt: -1 },
    },
  ],
},
```

If I run this query, I don't get the expected result, however, if I run this other one, I find it.

```
Matches.find({
  user_one: [
    {
      user: userId,
      punctuation: 0,
    },
  ],
},
```

How can I search for a document that has the "user" in the "user_one" array equal to the userId regardless of the punctuation?

Answer (score 0):

This looks good.

```
Matches.find({ 'user_one.user': userId })
```